# What does numpy's exp with multiple arguments?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

In the code of sklearn (in [logistic.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L297)) I see

```
p=np.exp(p,p)
```

What is np.exp(p,p)?

Comment: Look at the docs, parameters are `x`, `out` and `where`.  Usually `out` is provided as a keyword parameter, so its role is clearer.  If you get a casting error, it's because the `out` parameter has the wrong dtype.  It should be float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the inplace version of `np.exp(p)`. To avoid having to allocate a new array.

```
p = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
np.exp(p, p)
print(p) # array([ 2.71828183,  7.3890561 , 20.08553692])
```

Syntax: `np.exp(input_array, output_array)`

Comment: When I do np.exp(p,p) in ipython, I get an error msg: TypeError: ufunc 'exp' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode 'l') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''

Comment: @ericj, check the data type of `p` (i.e. `p.dtype`) before you call `np.exp(p, p)`.  Be sure it has a *floating point* type, not an integer type.